# How can I automatically resize the root partition on first boot?

Tags: berryboot

I'm preparing an image for download based on Raspbian. I can resize the partition manually using `raspi-config`. However, I'd prefer this to be automatic during first boot (maybe with a timeout for cancelling if such is possible).

Apparently BerryBoot is able to do this automatically- would appreciate a hint how this is done.

Comment: Some googling has found https://github.com/billw2/rpi-clone/blob/master/rpi-clone which contains shell code to do part of the work using parted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. make yourself a script that deletes or disables itself after first run (init for background or .profile for foreground)

> ```
> grep -v custom_script.sh ~/.profile > ~/.profile.new && mv ~/.profile.new ~/.profile
> ```

2. extract the bits you want from raspi-config (line 36 to to 116)

> ```
> > file $(which raspi-config)
> /usr/bin/raspi-config: POSIX shell script, ASCII text executable
> ```

Comment: Could you elaborate how the script would disable/delete itself?

Comment: @andig elaboration added